# How to chain writeFile() and OCR with NodeJS in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The scenario is as follows:

From an Amazon S3 bucket a file is fetched, then it is stored in a temporary folder and then Object Character Recognition is to be performed using the API. 
Unfortunately, this doesn't work, I think it's due to the asynchronous/synchronous execution, but I've already tried several variants with callbacks/promises and didn't get any further. 
If someone can give me a hint on how to construct this scenario I would be grateful!

The current error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined at Response.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:38:32) (it's the 'await fs.writeFile(dir,data);' line)


/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
var os = require('os');

exports.helloWorld = async (req,res) => {

    var bucket, fileName, fileUrl;
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        bucket = JSON.parse(data).value1;
        fileName = JSON.parse(data).value2;
        fileUrl = JSON.parse(data).value3;

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        s3.getObject({
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: fileName
            },
            async function(error, data) {
                if (error != null) {
                    console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
                } else {
                    console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentType + " bytes");
                    var tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
                    var dir = tmpdir+'/'+fileName;
                    try{
                      await fs.writeFile(dir,data);
                      const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
                      let text;
                      await vision
                          .textDetection('/tmp/' + fileName)
                          .then(([detections]) => {
                              const annotation = detections.textAnnotations[0];
                              console.log(1);
                              text = annotation ? annotation.description : '';
                              console.log(`Extracted text from image (${text.length} chars)`);
                              console.log(1);
                              console.log(text);
                              resolve("Finished ocr successfully");
                          })
                          .catch(error =>{
                            console.log(error);
                            reject("Error with OCR");
                          })
                    }catch(error){
                      console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            },
        );

        let message = bucket + fileName + fileUrl;
        res.status(200).send(message);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error, because you're running on an older version of Node (`< 10.0.0`), where `fs.promises` is not available. That's why `fs` is undefined, and you're getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined at Response.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:38:32) (it's the 'await fs.writeFile(dir,data);' line)
```

Either use a newer version, or just promisify the code.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
// const fs = require('fs').promises

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
```

And now use `writeFile` instead of `fs.writeFile` in your code.

---

Aside from that, there are a few issues with your code.

```
 req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
        data.push(chunk);
    });
```

`data` is not defined anywhere, and it doesn't make sense to push data into an array and then running `JSON.parse` on that array, given the next few lines.

```
bucket = JSON.parse(data).value1;
fileName = JSON.parse(data).value2;
fileUrl = JSON.parse(data).value3;
```

Furthermore, `JSON.parse` should be called only once, instead of parsing the same string (which is an array in your code, and will yield an error) 3 times.

```
const values = JSON.parse(body); // should be body instead of data with the posted code
bucket = values.value1;
fileName = values.value2;
fileUrl = values.value3;
```

This can be improved greatly by just posting `bucket`, `fileName` & `fileUrl` in the `JSON` instead of `valueN`.

```
const { bucket, fileName, fileUrl } = JSON.parse(body);
```

---

The whole code can be rewritten into:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);


exports.helloWorld = async (req,res) => {

    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();        
    });

    req.on('end', async() => {
        // post { "bucket": "x", "fileName": "x", "fileUrl": "x" }
        const { bucket, fileName, fileUrl } = JSON.parse(body);

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        try {

          const data = await s3.getObject({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: fileName
          }).promise();

          const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
          const filePath = path.join(tmpdir, fileName)

          await writeFile(filePath, data);

          const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();          
          const [detections] = await vision.textDetection(filePath)
          const annotation = detections.textAnnotations[0];
          const text = annotation ? annotation.description : '';
          console.log(`Extracted text from image (${text.length} chars)`);


          let message = bucket + fileName + fileUrl;
          res.status(200).send(message);

        } catch(e) {
          console.error(e);
          res.status(500).send(e.message);
        }
    });
};
```

NOTE: I don't know if `Vision` API works like this, but I used the same logic and parameters that you're using.

Comment: thanks for your help it worked, I didn't know about promisify